# What to call a polynomial that with no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ but does in $p$-adics

Tags: terminology, p-adic-number-theory

As an example, consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-2$. This polynomial has no roots over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. However, $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}_7$, so it does have roots in the 7-adics. Is there a name for this property? Is there a more elegant way of saying: Suppose $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $p$ is prime for which $f(x)$ has all its roots in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Or, alternatively, if you have an algebraic $\alpha$, is there an established terminology the describes whether or not $\mathbb{Q}_p$ contains an isomorphic copy of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that there should be a special name for a polynomial having all of its roots in $\mathbb{R}$ (beyond just *"a polynomial that splits over $\mathbb{R}$"*), so I suspect there's no need for a special name in the case of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: For your other question: if I wanted to say colloquially that, for example, $\mathbb{Q}_5$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, I would just say by abuse of notation that $i\in\mathbb{Q}_5$.

Comment: There actually is a (fairly) standard way of saying that $\Bbb Q_p$ contains an isomorphic copy of a field $K$: you say that there is an embedding of $K$ into $\Bbb Q_p$.